# Purple screen when installing Ubuntu 20.04 on late 2008 MacBook Pro 15"

Tags: macbook-pro

A few months ago I tried to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and MacOS on 15" late 2008 MacBook Pro, and each time the installation finished and I rebooted, I got stuck on a purple screen, after trying a few times I discovered that if I do a minimal install it works.
Then a few days ago I booted up the Mac to find the same purple screen, so I rebooted into MacOS (el capitan) and managed to back up all my files. Then I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but it didn't work.

What can I do?

Edit: I installed Ubuntu mate 20.04.1 and it worked, so maybe Ubuntu 20.04.1 works as well. If you know please answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, if you leave it on the purple screen does it eventually boot?

Comment: It boots into the purple screen, i can change the screen brightness and volume using the keyboard.